# How is this pipe removed? Seems to have 2 points to be released

Tags: bathroom, pipe, sink

I am looking into how I can unclog my bathroom sink.
I am looking at the pipe underneath and it seems that it has 2 points that can be used to be released. Why is this? Does it matter which to use?
This is the v shaped pipe underneath the bathroom sink we usually remove when the sink is clogged.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a double-ended compression coupling.  It is used because most people cannot spin their sinks or houses around to unscrew them.

Use a pipe wrench to unscrew both ends of that coupling to gain better access to the pipe.

Comment: 1) Should both be turned to the same direction? Which is as you see the photo to the right? 2) I unscrew both and I get 2 parts?

Comment: They will be opposite eachother.  The top one most likely unscrews to the left, and bottom to the right.  When unscrewed, you will be able to pull out the stub of pipe between those two red boxes, and the rings inside the boxes will rattle around on the ends of that stub.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `It is used because most people cannot spin their sinks or houses around to unscrew them.` to be honest

Comment: You need compression couplers to join two stationary objects.  Your sink, and the rest of your house' plumbing is stationary.

Comment: i thought your comment about turning the house was funny

Comment: Seems like loosening the bottom ring would be enough - no need to do both.  I would expect the top to be a tailpiece rather than compression.

Comment: Actually I managed to remove it but the bottom unscrews to the left not to the right